# Animate several views with one animation resource

Tags: android, animation

hello!

I was about implementing scale animation for click feedback on view. Here is an animation resource:

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">

    <scale        
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"        
        android:duration="180"
        android:repeatCount="1"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" />    

</set>
```

Activity code:

```
private View.OnClickListener mButtonsListener;
mButtonsListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        v.startAnimation(mBounceAnimation);
    }

};
oneBtn.setOnClickListener(mButtonsListener);
twoChb.setOnClickListener(mButtonsListener);
threeChb.setOnClickListener(mButtonsListener);
```

When I click on one of the buttons and allow animation to complete and then click on another button - it's OK. But when I click on one button and then before animation was completed click another button, animation on first button restarts. This restarting is my problem((
I would like to have independent animation drawing for each of three buttons.

Could you tell me what should I do to resolve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: create one animation per button, not one animation used by all buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add independent `onClickListeners` to each of your `Buttons`and also three independent `Animation` objects, referring to the same resourse. Like this:

```
    final Animation mBounceAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.scale);
    final Animation mBounceAnimation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.scale);
    final Animation mBounceAnimation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.scale);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);

    oneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAct);
    twoChb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twoChb);
    threeChb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.threeChb);

    oneBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.startAnimation(mBounceAnimation);

        }
    });

    twoChb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(mBounceAnimation1);

        }
    });

    threeChb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.startAnimation(mBounceAnimation2);

        }
    });
```

This way, your `Animations` are not interrupted and are behaviouring independently.

Comment: honestly, I don't know why I didn't do it myself. Thought of using one resource and one reference to it filled my mind). But it works, thnx